# Check type overloads a given operator

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

There are many related questions on this topic, but I am still puzzled by the following case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A {};
struct B { void operator + (const B& /* other */) {} };
struct C { C operator + (const C& /* other */) {return *this;} };
struct D { D& operator + (const D& /* other */) {return *this;} };

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_p_op : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_p_op<T, decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    constexpr bool a = has_p_op<A>::value; // false
    constexpr bool b = has_p_op<B>::value; // true
    constexpr bool c = has_p_op<C>::value; // false
    constexpr bool d = has_p_op<D>::value; // false
    std::cout << a << b << c << d << std::endl;
}
```

why aren't `c` and `d` both `true`?

Comment: Because the return type of the expression is not `void`? This is also why we have `std::void_t`.

Comment: Was about to post "but I tried `decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>(), void)` and it did not work" and now I see I missed the parenthesis in `void()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning the `void` type was missing.

v1:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_p_op<T, decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>(), void())> : std::true_type {};
```

v2:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_p_op<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type {};
```